# Large document XPath query performance

Tags: xml, xpath, libxml2

With 5 MB document, the following query takes `libxml2` 3 seconds to evaluate. Is there anything I could do to speed things up? I need the resulting node-set for further processing, so no `count`, etc.

Thanks!

```
descendant::text() | descendant::*
[
self::p or
self::h1 or
self::h2 or
self::h3 or
self::h4 or
self::h5 or
self::h6 or
self::dl or
self::dt or
self::dd or
self::ol or
self::ul or
self::li or
self::dir or
self::address or
self::blockquote or
self::center or
self::del or
self::div or
self::hr or
self::ins or
self::pre
]
```

**Edit:**

Using `descendant::node()[self::text() or self::p or ...` as suggested by *Jens Erat* (see the accepted answer) significantly improved the speed; from the original 2.865330s to just perfect 0.164336s.

Comment: I'd love to see some feedback on your benchmarking for the different proposals in here.

Comment: @JensErat I've measured it and edited my question. Thanks a lot for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Benchmarking without any document to benchmark on is very difficult.

Two ideas for optimizing:

- Use as few `descendant::` axis steps as possible. They're expensive and probably you can speed up a little bit. You can combine the `text()` and element tests like this:

  ```
  descendant::node()[self::text() or self::h1 or self::h2]
  ```

  and extend for all elements (I'm keeping the query short for better readability).
- Use string-tests instead of node tests. They *could* be faster (probably aren't, see the comments to the answer). You need to keep the `text()` test, of course.

  ```
  descendant::node()[self::text() or local-name(.) = 'h1' or local-name(.) = 'h2']
  ```

---

If you're often querying the same document, think about using a native XML database like BaseX, eXist DB, Zorba, Marklogic, ... (the first three are free). They're putting indices on your data and should be able to serve the results *much  faster* (and support XPath 2.0/XQuery, which makes developing much easier). All of them have APIs for a large set of programming languages.

Comment: I'm familiar with some of the internals of the XPath engine in libxml2, and using `local-name()` instead of a NodeTest is certainly slower. Your first suggestion should result in a measurable speedup, though.

Comment: I just tried your first suggestion on a test document and it resulted in a 15x speedup.

Comment: Wow, that's about 14x faster than I expected. ;) @nwellnhof do you have a guess why that happened?

Comment: It's mainly because libxml2 sorts the result of a union to make sure that the nodes are in document order.

Comment: Still seems weird to me, all it has to do is doing a merge step of merge sort which is O(n). I expected it taking about double performance (one time less scanning the file), but not such a _huge_ improvement. Is there any kind of query plan that can be dumped?

Comment: libxml2 isn't smart enough to use a merge sort in this situation. Newer versions use Timsort and older versions use Shellsort which is even slower than `O(n*log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have libxml2 compiled with the --with-threads option enabled? If so, the most straightforward thing to do would be to throw a faster processor with more cores at the problem

Comment: libxml2 doesn't make use of threads to speed up evaluation of XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is equivalent to

```
(descendant::text() | descendant::p
    | descendant::h1  | descendant::h2  | descendant::h3 | descendant::h4  | descendant::h5 | descendant::h6
    | descendant::dl  | descendant::dt  | descendant::dd | descendant::ol  | descendant::ul | descendant::li
    | descendant::dir | descendant::address | descendant::blockquote | descendant::center
    | descendant::del | descendant::div | descendant::hr | descendant::ins | descendant::pre
)
```

But I am not able to measure any difference in its speed.

Comment: I guess it will be slower instead of faster as the document (needs to | could) be scanned multiple times, one for each `descendant`-step. I'm not sure about how clever libxml2 optimizes.

Comment: This is much slower than the original query used in my question. See @JensErat's answer.